# Is there a monero vanity address generator?

Tags: address-reuse

Is there a xmr vanity address generator where you can type in a string and it will keep generating until it matches your criteria?

I want to find an address with my name in the beginning of it. Which characters are not allowed in a xmr address?

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://xmr.llcoins.net/ and open up the Javascript console. Then run the command:

```
while(document.getElementById('pubAddr').value.substring(2).toLowerCase().indexOf('ABC'.toLowerCase())!=0) allRandom(); alert('done');
```

or to make a case sensitive match:

```
while(document.getElementById('pubAddr').value.substring(2).indexOf('ABC')!=0) allRandom(); alert('done');
```

(replacing 'ABC' with the string you're looking for).

Beware, brute force generation of Monero addresses requires elliptic curve multiplication, which is a slow operation. If you attempt a match that is longer than 2 or 3 characters, expect a wait of several hours. The time required for a match will rise geometrically with each additional character in the match string.

Monero addresses are represented in base 58, so you can have any alphanumeric characters excluding 0 (zero), O (capital o), I (capital i) and l (lower case L).

Comment: how did you figure this out? is there something for the command line and eve possibly optimized for gpu / cpu address generation?

Comment: I just wrote code that emulated pushing the "random" button on that web site until it came up with the correct result, it was pretty straightforward. There isn't any off-the-shelf GPU code capable of doing EC multiplication, so you'd need to use a CPU. It'd be possible to write one in C that used the existing Monero libraries, but I'm not aware of anything that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

This one works: https://moneroaddress.org

It is created by and gpg signed by Monero mooo. Use it offline, on an **air-gapped** system.

https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/